# Add monthList On Fullcalendar 2.4.0 Version

Tags: fullcalendar

I managed to add listWeek on Fullcalendar.js Version 2.4.0 , but how can i add listMonth?

Code I Have added for listWeek is shown below 
Want to add monthList View to fullcalendar version 2.4. 0

```
var ListView = fcViews.list = View.extend({
    dayGrid: null, // the main subcomponent that does most of the heavy lifting
    weekNumberWidth: null, // width of all the week-number cells running down the side
    headRowEl: null, // the fake row element of the day-of-week header
    //defultEventLimit: 5, //we need to show some events in each cell 
    viewDateOnLeft: false, //true to display date on left, false to display above the day
initialize: function() {
    this.dayGrid = new DayGrid(this);
    this.coordMap = this.dayGrid.coordMap; // the view's date-to-cell mapping is identical to the subcomponent's
},

// Sets the display range and computes all necessary dates
setRange: function(range) {
    View.prototype.setRange.call(this, range); // call the super-method

    this.dayGrid.breakOnWeeks = /year|month|week/.test(this.intervalUnit); // do before setRange
    this.dayGrid.setRange(range);
},

// Renders the view into `this.el`, which should already be assigned.
renderDates: function() {
    this.dayGrid.colCnt = 1;
    this.dayGrid.rowCnt = this.dayGrid.cellDates.length;
    this.dayGrid.numbersVisible = true;

    if (this.opt('viewDateOnLeft')) {
        this.viewDateOnLeft = this.opt('viewDateOnLeft');
        this.el.removeClass('fc-display-date-above');
    } else {
        this.el.addClass('fc-display-date-above');
    }

    this.el.addClass('fc-basic-view').html(this.renderHtml());

    this.headRowEl = this.el.find('thead fc-row');

    this.scrollerEl = this.el.find('.fc-day-grid-container');
    this.dayGrid.coordMap.containerEl = this.scrollerEl; // constrain clicks/etc to the dimensions of the scroller

    this.dayGrid.el = this.el.find('.fc-day-grid');
    this.dayGrid.renderDates(this.hasRigidRows());
},

// Make subcomponents ready for cleanup
unrenderDates: function() {
    this.dayGrid.unrenderDates();
    this.dayGrid.removeElement();
},


// Builds the HTML skeleton for the view.
renderHtml: function() {
    return '' +
        '<div class="' + this.widgetContentClass + '">' +
        '<div class="fc-day-grid-container">' +
        '<div class="fc-day-grid"/>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>';
},


// Generates the HTML that will go before the day-of week header cells.
// Queried by the DayGrid subcomponent when generating rows. Ordering depends on isRTL.
headIntroHtml: function() {
    if (this.viewDateOnLeft === true) {
        return '' +
            '<th class="fc-week-number ' + this.widgetHeaderClass + '" ' + this.weekNumberStyleAttr() + '>' +
            '<span>' +
            '</span>' +
            '</th>';
    } else {
        return '';
    }
},


// Generates the HTML that will go before content-skeleton cells that display the day/week numbers.
// Queried by the DayGrid subcomponent. Ordering depends on isRTL.
numberIntroHtml: function(row) {
    if (this.viewDateOnLeft === true) {
        return '' +
            '<td class="fc-week-number" ' + this.weekNumberStyleAttr() + '>' +
            '<span>' + // needed for matchCellWidths
            this.dayGrid.getCell(row, 0).start.format('ddd MMM D, YYYY') +
            '</span>' +
            '</td>';
    } else {
        return '';
    }
},


// Generates the HTML that goes before the day bg cells for each day-row.
// Queried by the DayGrid subcomponent. Ordering depends on isRTL.
dayIntroHtml: function() {
    if (this.viewDateOnLeft === true) {
        return '<td class="fc-week-number ' + this.widgetContentClass + '" ' +
            this.weekNumberStyleAttr() + '></td>';
    } else {
        return '';
    }
},


// Generates the HTML that goes before every other type of row generated by DayGrid. Ordering depends on isRTL.
// Affects helper-skeleton and highlight-skeleton rows.
introHtml: function() {
    if (this.viewDateOnLeft === true) {
        return '<td class="fc-week-number" ' + this.weekNumberStyleAttr() + '></td>';
    } else {
        return '';
    }
},


// Generates the HTML for the <td>s of the "number" row in the DayGrid's content skeleton.
// The number row will only exist if either day numbers or week numbers are turned on.
numberCellHtml: function(cell) {
    if (this.viewDateOnLeft === true) {
        return '<td/>';
    } else {
        var date = cell.start;
        var classes;

        classes = this.dayGrid.getDayClasses(date);
        classes.unshift('my-fc-header');
        return '' +
            '<div class="' + classes.join(' ') + '" data-date="' + date.format() + '">' +
            '<span class="my-fc-header-day">' +
            date.format('dddd') +
            '</span>' +
            '<span class="my-fc-header-date">' +
            date.format('DD-MM-YYYY') +
            '</span>' +
            '</div>';
    }
},


// Generates an HTML attribute string for setting the width of the week number column, if it is known
weekNumberStyleAttr: function() {
    if (this.weekNumberWidth !== null) {
        return 'style="width:' + this.weekNumberWidth + 'px"';
    }
    return '';
},


// Determines whether each row should have a constant height
hasRigidRows: function() {
    var eventLimit = this.opt('eventLimit');
    if (eventLimit === true) {
        eventLimit = this.defultEventLimit;
    }

    return eventLimit && typeof eventLimit !== 'number';
},


/* Dimensions
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/


// Refreshes the horizontal dimensions of the view
updateWidth: function() {
    // Make sure all week number cells running down the side have the same width.
    // Record the width for cells created later.
    this.weekNumberWidth = matchCellWidths(
        this.el.find('.fc-week-number')
    );
},


// Adjusts the vertical dimensions of the view to the specified values
setHeight: function(totalHeight, isAuto) {
    var eventLimit = this.opt('eventLimit');
    if (eventLimit === true) {
        eventLimit = this.defultEventLimit;
    }
    var scrollerHeight;

    // reset all heights to be natural
    unsetScroller(this.scrollerEl);
    uncompensateScroll(this.headRowEl);

    this.dayGrid.removeSegPopover(); // kill the "more" popover if displayed

    // is the event limit a constant level number?
    if (eventLimit && typeof eventLimit === 'number') {
        this.dayGrid.limitRows(eventLimit); // limit the levels first so the height can redistribute after
    }

    scrollerHeight = this.computeScrollerHeight(totalHeight);
    this.setGridHeight(scrollerHeight, isAuto);

    // is the event limit dynamically calculated?
    if (eventLimit && typeof eventLimit !== 'number') {
        this.dayGrid.limitRows(eventLimit); // limit the levels after the grid's row heights have been set
    }

    if (!isAuto && setPotentialScroller(this.scrollerEl, scrollerHeight)) { // using scrollbars?

        compensateScroll(this.headRowEl, getScrollbarWidths(this.scrollerEl));

        // doing the scrollbar compensation might have created text overflow which created more height. redo
        scrollerHeight = this.computeScrollerHeight(totalHeight);
        this.scrollerEl.height(scrollerHeight);

        this.restoreScroll();
    }
},


// Sets the height of just the DayGrid component in this view
setGridHeight: function(height, isAuto) {
    if (isAuto) {
        undistributeHeight(this.dayGrid.rowEls); // let the rows be their natural height with no expanding
    } else {
        distributeHeight(this.dayGrid.rowEls, height, true); // true = compensate for height-hogging rows
    }
},


/* Events
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/


// Sets the view's title property to the most updated computed value
updateTitle: function() {
    this.title = this.computeTitle();
},


// Computes what the title at the top of the calendar should be for this view
computeTitle: function() {
    return "Week of activity " + this.formatRange({
            start: this.intervalStart,
            end: this.intervalEnd
        },
        this.opt('titleFormat') || this.computeTitleFormat(),
        this.opt('titleRangeSeparator')
    );
},


// Renders the given events onto the view and populates the segments array
renderEvents: function(events) {
    this.dayGrid.renderEvents(events);
    //console.log(events);
    /*var out = '';
jQuery.each(events, function(key, value){
     this.dayGrid.renderEvents(value.description);
});*/

    this.updateHeight(); // must compensate for events that overflow the row

    View.prototype.renderEvents.call(this, events); // call the super-method
},

// Retrieves all segment objects that are rendered in the view
getSegs: function() {
    return this.dayGrid.getSegs();
},


// Unrenders all event elements and clears internal segment data
unrenderEvents: function() {
    this.dayGrid.unrenderEvents();

    // we DON'T need to call updateHeight() because:
    // A) a renderEvents() call always happens after this, which will eventually call updateHeight()
    // B) in IE8, this causes a flash whenever events are rerendered
},


/* Event Dragging
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/


// Renders a visual indication of an event being dragged over the view.
// A returned value of `true` signals that a mock "helper" event has been rendered.
renderDrag: function(start, end, seg) {
    return this.dayGrid.renderDrag(start, end, seg);
},


// Unrenders the visual indication of an event being dragged over the view
destroyDrag: function() {
    this.dayGrid.destroyDrag();
},


/* Selection
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/


// Renders a visual indication of a selection
renderSelection: function(start, end) {
    this.dayGrid.renderSelection(start, end);
},


// Unrenders a visual indications of a selection
destroySelection: function() {
    this.dayGrid.destroySelection();
}
});

;;

/* A list view with simple day cells
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

fcViews.listWeek = {
  type: 'list',
  duration: {
    weeks: 1
  }
};

  ;;
  return fc; // export for Node/CommonJS
});
```

[verison3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipXoF.png)

[listweek_in_version_2.4.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxW91.png)

Comment: not sure what you mean by "added listWeek"? There's already a view built in called listWeek, and another called listMonth. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Available_Views/ All you have to do is add a menu item to it when you initialise the calendar. Have you written your own custom view for it? Is that what this mountain of code is?

Comment: Yes i Know , but I am using fullcalendar.js But Version is 2.4.0  and this version dont have built in listWeek, listMonth , so i wanted to add it to my calendar . i added listWeek using the code i have given , Now how to add listMonth View . if i update my fullcalendar Version to 3 which supports this View the problem is it shows object Object in Header Instead of Days Names
see screenshort  For both listWeek i added and if i update to Version 3 the calendar look

Comment: I have added two images above name version3 and listweek_in_version_2.4.0

Comment: Yes i have added a custom view.

Comment: I can't tell you why it does that in version 3 because you haven't shown how you are setting up the calendar. But there's no reason it should do that, it's most likely a bug in your code. Updating to v3 and getting it working will be much easier than making another custom view, and then you won't have to maintain the one you've written, either.